# How to upload multiple files using Swings Applications?

Tags: java, swing

I m trying to upload multiple files in swings applications.I have declared an array to hold the values of selected files but when i click on upload button only 1 file is getting uploaded. How can i upload all selected files into database?

The code to Open and Upload File is ....

```
 public void openFile() 
 {
      JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
      jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);// added line
      int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);
      if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) return;
      try {
            ArrayList<String> FileData = new ArrayList<String>();
            File[] file = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
            String s=""; int c=0;
            for(int i=0;i<file.length;i++) //added
            {  
              jep.setText(file[i].toString()); // added
            }
            return FileData;
          } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage(),
            "File error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          }
   }
```

Comment: Show us the code where you upload / persist the data, please. Left my crystal ball at home...

Comment: It seems the problem is in the code behind the button, and not the button itself. You should look there.

Comment: Swing is NOT part of J2EE. In the future Swing questions, just tag `[swing]`, not `[j2ee]`.

Comment: Your code snippet is not correct: you return array list on void method, didn't show us where you defined jep, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // get list of selected files
    File[] file = jfc.getSelectedFiles();
    String s=""; int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<file.length;i++) //added
    {  
      // The toString will just return you back the path of the file object times the number of bytes in the file.
      jep.setText(file[i].toString()); // added
    }
    return FileData;
```

This code will not work. If you want a method to read a file given a file name into an array of Strings then you will need:

```
   /**
    * Read entire contents of a text file.
    *
    * @param fileName Text file name
    * @return ArrayList of String (line) elements
    * @throws FileNotFoundException
    * @throws IOException
    */
   public static ArrayList readTextFile( String fileName )
      throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
      ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
      BufferedReader in = null;
      try
      {
         in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName ));
         String line;
         while ( ( line = in.readLine()) != null )
         {
            lines.add( line );
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         if ( in != null )
         {
            try
            {
               in.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException ex )
            {
            }
         }
      }
      return lines;
   }
```

Since you want to read in the contents of several file, just do this in a loop and do each one individually. If you load it all in memory you might run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clearly defined what you actually mean by "upload multiple files". I'm presuming that you wish to load the **contents** of multiple text files one after the other into a single `JEditorPane`. If that is the case, Romain's answer shows you an example of loading a single file.
What your code is actually doing though is looping through the array of `File` objects and setting their *path* (that is what `toString` returns on `File`) as the text within your editor pane. Each one is overriding the last, so that is why you end up with a single file path.
I might also suggest when you pop up your `JFileChooser` you limit the files a user can select to specific file types (e.g. txt, html).